# GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework has an incorrect or unknown format and cannot be processed

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2022, google-mobile-ads

I really don't know if this is specific to the package or to xcframework or to the setup. In my case I just:

- open VS 2022
- create a Xamarin iOS empty project
- add the Google Mobile Ads 8.13.0.1 Nuget package through the VS NuGet package manager ( this is the package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds/)
- build
- get this error:

C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\GAppM-8.9.1\GoogleAppMeasurement-8.9.1\Frameworks\GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework has an incorrect or unknown format and cannot be processed.

I've been using google ads in iOS projects for 10 years, updates tend to screw everything up, but it's usually fixable, this time I'm completely stuck.

I tried filing a bug report (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/GoogleAppMeasurementxcframework-has-an/10153891?entry=problem) and an issue on github (https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/573) , but experience tells me it's useless...

[EDIT]
The project is here:
http://www.andreasabbatini.org/Files/AdmobTest.zip

Comment: Very vague description. Where do you get this xcframework from?

Comment: obviously here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds/ but through the NuGet interface on Visual Studio

Comment: Have you added the `appropriate keys` to the info.plist? Please refer to [this link](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#update_your_infoplist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I “think” I have found a solution, if not the cause. I cannot replicate it relably, but sometimes it happens sometimes not.

(in a brand new PC or VS install)
1-Create a project similar to that one. Add the Google Ads NuGet package. Build. The build works

2-Create another project (or use that one, it’s the same). Add the same Google Ads NuGet package, then the Xamarin.Facebook.AudienceNetwork.iOS 6.9.0.1 https://github.com/xamarin/FacebookComponents/tree/main/Facebook.iOS/source/AudienceNetwork
build this or the other project, for some strange reason, the above error starts to appear

3-remove the above facebook package, the error is still there. I’ve tried many things here, readding packages, etc none work

4-remove the packages, delete manually C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache and readd the packages one at a time. Most of the time it works, but sometimes I have to repeat this step.

Comment: I have the same problem on my Mac machine. Where would XamarinBuildDownloadCache folder be? I don't even have Google Ads NuGet package either

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't have Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds in my project, but I do have Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.*. I tried uninstalling all the packages and installing them again, but I still get the same error.

Comment: I ended up just removing all the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.* packages as I don't need them anymore, and it now build fine. But I can confirm that there is a problem for anyone with google-related packages.

Comment: I am not sure, but I would think packages get corrupted when installing other packages or just by themselves. Nuget is finnicky, but the VS implementation on top of Xamarin other complications, makes everything pretty fragile. I suggest removing the packages, deleting both caches and maybe try to readd the packages. Since I started using xamarin I spent ages trying to pinpoint these types of errors, but in the end most of the times it's just that stuff gets corrupted randomly...